# How to connect to another JFrame only after succesful login

Tags: java

i have created a login page and want to link it to another Jframe only after successful login

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   if(jTextField1.getText().length()==0)
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"insert username");
   else if(jPasswordField1.getPassword().length==0)
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"insert password");
   else{
       String user = jTextField1.getText();
       char[] pass = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
       String pwd = String.copyValueOf(pass);
       if(validate_login(user,pwd))
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct User");
       else
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect User or Password!");
   }
}
```

i expect  a line of code to take me to a new JFrame

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply create a `JFrame` object and set its basic properies:

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("your title");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 //Create components and put them in the frame.
 frame.getContentPane().add(/* ... */);
 //Size the frame.
 frame.pack();
 //Show
 frame.setVisible(true);
```

Now it's up to you what to do with the original window. If you want to close it:

```
 //suppose "origFrame" is your original JFframe
 origFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```